# Java : Byte array prints unknown values for same string

Tags: java, arrays, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following `String` which is stored in a text file and also as a variable in Java : ***‘destructive’***

My code below

```
public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("TestFIle.txt");
            byte[] file_encoded = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(file_encoded));

            String toEncrypt = "‘destructive’";
            byte[] encoded = toEncrypt.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encoded));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see

```
String toEncrypt = "‘destructive’";
```

The contents in **TestFIle.txt** is also : ‘destructive’

When i run the code i get:

```
[-17, -69, -65, -30, -128, -104, 100, 101, 115, 116, 114, 117, 99, 116, 105, 118, 101, -30, -128, -103]
[-30, -128, -104, 100, 101, 115, 116, 114, 117, 99, 116, 105, 118, 101, -30, -128, -103]
```

What is the additional `[-17, -69,  -65]` at the starting of byte array while reading the same text from a file and why do i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leading `[-17, -69, -65]` is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of UTF-8.
In hexadecimal the BOM is `[0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]` which is actually `[239, 187, 191]`.
But because Java's `byte` is signed, the numbers are interpreted (and printed) as negative numbers.

In general, the BOM is optional and it seems to be common in the Microsoft ecosystem: https://superuser.com/questions/1553666/utf-8-vs-utf-8-with-bom

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems to contain text encoded in UTF-8 with a leading [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The BOM for UTF-8 is EF BB BF. In two's complement representation this is -17 -69 -65.